# (HTML + CCS3 Generated Content for Paged Media) to PDF?

Tags: html, css, xhtml, pdf-generation, css-paged-media

Is there any way to render a PDF from a HTML doc styled with [CSS3 Generated Content for Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-gcpm/#page-floats)?

If there is not an application like that, what can I use as a base to build such a converter?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "render a PDF"?

Comment: @hitautodestruct: I'm sure Victor means "convert HTML to PDF".

Comment: I request this Q be reopened as it is useful & specific & {{the rule cited for closing it: ‘too broad’}'s latest form http://archive.is/oVqrS#selection-475.0-481.1 does NOT apply as this Q (1) would not need answer by ‘an entire book‘, (2) NOT ‘has many valid answers’ (only a few, at least for _automated_ ‘render a PDF’ as is intended), and (3) there IS fairly straightforward ‘way to determine which [answers] - if any - are correct’.  So plz undo the Q currently being ‘closed as too broad by Nicol Bolas, user2314737, greg-449, mpromonet, lokusking Sep 18 '16 at 9:51’, and note my next cmt...

Comment: Continuing my previous cmt, note the cited ‘too broad’ reason for closing this Q now has {the exception I cited of ‘(but no way to determine which [answers] - if any - are correct)’  http://archive.is/oVqrS#selection-477.82-481.1 } {which IMHO is long overdue as it stops 2 types of malign closing of good Qs} and {which was added a day after https://web.archive.org/web/20170320191936/http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions (as that URL shows) so on 2017.03.21} so added next year AFTER when this Q's ‘closed as too broad’ ruling was made so notably further rendering-invalid this closing.

Comment: Works using https://www.pagedjs.org/ in all major browsers. Give it a try!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They only application ***I*** know of that can possibly convert HTML/CSS3 to good quality PDF is [PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/features/). (And it is my impression, that Google licensed and utilizes their code somehow in GoogleDocs for PDF export.)

However, this is a commercial application, and I think it comes with a hefty price tag.

One of it's leading lights is Håkon Lie, who is also behind all the technical achievements of the Opera web browser.

Here is a 2 years old Google Tech Talks video where Lie outlines some of the technologie behind PrinceXML:

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vcXUrNSvjhU

Comment: Glad it solved your problem. :-)

Answer (score 1):

wkhtmltopdf should handle this very nicely.

http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

> Searching the web, I have found
>   several command line tools that allow
>   you to convert a HTML-document to a
>   PDF-document, however they all seem to
>   use their own, and rather incomplete
>   rendering engine, resulting in poor
>   quality. Recently QT 4.4 was released
>   with a WebKit widget (WebKit is the
>   engine of Apples Safari, which is a
>   fork of the KDE KHtml), and making a
>   good tool became very easy.good tool became very easy.

Comment: very interesting, but still very young. Thanks Bart!

Answer (score 0):

[DOMPDF](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) is an open source PHP project to convert HTML to PDF documents, but it doesn't support CSS3 generated content, but the project is very active. You are welcome to participate !
It's CSS 2.1 support is pretty good, and a few CSS3 properties have been added recently in the SVN trunk.

Comment: Very promising, but still quite young. Thanks Fabien!

Comment: > written in PHP. uhh, no, thank you very much