# How to use html for desktop publishing?

Tags: html, css, pdf, publishing

Not considering ad-hoc programs (like Adobe Indesign, the open source Scribus or word processors), it seems to me that Latex is the only markup language used for document preparation able to generate beautiful PDF documents.

I thought that HTML + CSS would make a terrific combination for the purpose. HTML can be easily generated from a mid-layer format (like [markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/)), a bit of programming based on classes can generate indexes and notes (and so on) and CSS can really style a page with ease. Preparing a document would turn out to be way easier than using Latex that is incredibly powerful but making something "out of the standard" is really hard.

The hard part would be getting the PDF. While there are a number of programs (also [free](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/))
to get a PDF out of HTML, I can't see how to retain the concept of "page". One would write the document as a single, long HTML page and let the program split it into pages, apply footnotes, headers, page numbers...

Is there already such a program? Has anyone any idea on how to implement it? Thanks.

Comment: You can use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) to convert markdown or HTML to LaTeX...

Answer (score 7):

**Summary:** [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) is the best option if you're serious about a high quality HTML-to-PDF pipeline. If you don't want to pay for Prince, you will probably need to compromise on either document quality or your choice of pipeline.

---

There is [an excellent article on A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/boom) about this. They used [Prince](http://www.princexml.com/) and [CSS2 paged media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html) (as suggested by **widyakumara**) to produce pages with correctly-formatted numbers and the like. Prince is free for noncommercial use; commercial use licenses start at $3800 per server, which isn't so expensive when you consider how damn awesome Prince is.

A few cheaper alternatives were suggested in [an earlier Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3464256/html-ccs3-generated-content-for-paged-media-to-pdf) about converting HTML/CSS3 with generated content/paged media into PDF. I've tried a few of those, and I have to conclude that Prince is the only tool I've seen that can produce a paged PDF using features like generated page numbers from HTML and CSS. Prince also supports many print-specific features like footnotes.

That said, I'd suggest that this is a solution in search of a problem. HTML and CSS are proably not the best choice for documents that are intended to finish up as "beautiful PDF documents." LaTeX is not just a markup language; it is a mature, intelligent typesetting system whose goal is to produce attractive printed documents. In comparison, HTML and CSS are plainly not the best tools for the job.

Answer (score 3):

there's css [print media type](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types) & [paged media section](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html)

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered XSL-FO? [Apache FOP](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/) is free and may suit your needs.